# WiX: This feature will be installed to run from network

Tags: wix, windows-installer

WiX.

How does work this variant of the feature installing? How can I disable it? I see nothing about it [here](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/custom-settings/). My admin told to me that he nothing knows about it too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because this is an issue also in 2022, here one solution:

Inside your `<Feature>` add an empty `<ComponentRef Id="yourFeatureId"/>`

Ensure, that this referenced Component resist inside your TARGETDIR. This prevent the Network-target.

Example:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Component Id="yourFeatureId" Guid="{C8F07DC5-50C6-450E-A398-A520735FC5A9}" />
</DirectoryRef>
```

Works in my Project :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set InstallDefault to local in the Feature element, but it would help to see the WiX for the features involved.

Comment: Each my `Feature` element already has the `local` value for the `InstallDefault` attribute.